# Overriding DistributedMemoryCache to Use DistributedSQLCache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nopcommerce, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an aspnet core 2.2 application that uses DistributedMemoryCache, and I want to change it to DistributedSQLCache, without recompiling and changing that application (It's already compiled), so I want to add a plugin to it (it has a plugin system) to change the cache from memory cache to SQL cache. Is that possible, for example by calling ConfigureServices? I tried this  to no avail:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString =
                   "Data Source=etcetc....";
                options.SchemaName = "dbo";
                options.TableName = "TestCache";
            });

            services.AddMvc();

            
        }
```

How can I do that? I want to utilize SQL server caching to run a proper web garden and webfarm on this application.

Comment: If it does not support some dynamic plugins loading in this part of app the either way I'm afraid you will need to recompile it to make it support this.

Comment: You should state clearly that this is a question about NopCommerce (if it is, instead of "an aspnet core 2.2 application") because there is no generic answer for this, you need to use the platform services in order to do the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

NopCommerce currently supports Memory, SqlServer and Redis as cache types OTB.

In order to replace this or any other element that normally you would find in the ConfigureServices method you will need to provide a custom implementation for `INopStartup` in your plugin.